# Monoid type class in C++

Tags: c++, generics

I am trying to come up with a `monoid` type class in C++. Here I am giving a working example of what I have devised so far.

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

template<typename T, typename BinaryOp>
struct monoid
{
    //T mempty();
    //T mappend(T,T);
    static constexpr bool is_instance = false;
    using type = T;
};

template<>
struct monoid<int, std::plus<int>>
{
    static int mempty() { return 0 ;}
    static int mappend(int lhs, int rhs) {return lhs + rhs; }
    static constexpr bool is_instance = true;
    using type = int;
};

template<>
struct monoid<double, std::multiplies<double>>
{
    static double mempty() { return 1.0 ;}
    static double mappend(double lhs, double rhs) {return lhs * rhs; }
    static constexpr bool is_instance = true;
    using type = double;
};

template<>
struct monoid<int, std::multiplies<int>>
{
    static int mempty() { return 1 ;}
    static int mappend(int lhs, int rhs) {return lhs * rhs; }
    static constexpr bool is_instance = true;
    using type = int;
};

template <>
struct monoid<std::string, std::plus<std::string>> {
    static std::string mempty(){return std::string{};}
    static std::string mappend(std::string const& lhs,
                               std::string const& rhs){
        return lhs + rhs;
    }
    static constexpr bool is_instance = true;
    using type = std::string;
};

template <typename Container>
struct ContainerAppender{
    Container operator()(Container const& lhs, Container const& rhs)
    {
        Container dst;
        std::merge(std::begin(lhs), std::end(lhs),
                   std::begin(rhs), std::end(rhs),
                   std::back_inserter(dst));

        return dst;
    }
};

template <typename Container>
struct monoid<Container, ContainerAppender<Container>> {
    static Container mempty(){ return Container{}; }
    static Container mappend(Container const& lhs,
                             Container const& rhs){
        return ContainerAppender<Container>{}(lhs, rhs);
    }
    static constexpr bool is_instance = true;
    using type = Container;
};

template <typename T, typename BinaryOp>
constexpr bool is_monoid_v = monoid<T, BinaryOp>::is_instance;

template <typename T, typename BinaryOp>
using is_monoid = std::enable_if_t<is_monoid_v<T, BinaryOp>>;

template<template <typename> typename BinaryOp,
         typename ForwardIt,
         typename = is_monoid<typename ForwardIt::value_type,
                              BinaryOp<typename ForwardIt::value_type>>>
auto mconcat(const ForwardIt begin, const ForwardIt end)
{
    using T = typename ForwardIt::value_type;
    T out{monoid<T, BinaryOp<T>>::mempty()};
    for(ForwardIt it = begin; it != end; it++){
        out = monoid<T, BinaryOp<T>>::mappend(out,*it);
    }
    return out;
}

int main(){
    std::vector<std::string>str_vec{"1","2","3"};
    std::cout << mconcat<std::plus>(str_vec.begin(),
                                    str_vec.end())
              << "\n";

    std::list<double> dbl_li{1.0, 2.3, 4.5};
    double acc = mconcat<std::multiplies>(std::begin(dbl_li),
                                          std::end(dbl_li));
    std::cout << acc << "\n";

    // Reduce vectors as well, nested reduction
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> nested_vec{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    const auto v= mconcat<ContainerAppender>(std::begin(nested_vec),
                                             std::end(nested_vec));
    int res = mconcat<std::multiplies>(std::begin(v),
                                       std::end(v));
    std::cout << res << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

1. What are general code smells you can identify?
2. Are there any problems with my usage of templates and generic programming, how that can be improved?
3. Can you suggest improvements on usability and extendibility of `monoid` class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that the `mappend` function should be generated from the BinaryOp.  So that makes it the same in all your specializations, and the only thing you need is the matching `mempty`.

I think you should have a fully generic template that figures out `mappend` and `type` from the template arguments, and looks up the proper unit value for that operation using a smaller specialized metafunction.

---

Your `monoid::type` should be called `value_type`.  And you can get it from `declspec(monoid::mempty())` so do you really need a separate entry for that, and if so, shouldn’t you generate it automatically too?

Or, define the functions in terms of the nested `value_type` rather than peppering the specialization with `int` and `double` etc. in all the identical places.

Again, if you factor out `mempty`, the rest of that just goes away and you don’t need any explicit specializations for `monoid`.

```
template<typename T, typename BinaryOp, T unit = UnitFor_v<BinaryOp,T>>
struct monoid
{
    using value_type = T;
    static value_type mempty() { return unit; }
    static value_type mappend (T left,T right) { return BinaryOp()(left, right); }
    using type = T;
};
```

(deeper thought: I kept the params to `mappend` by simple value passing, which is probably right for types you’ll use for this, and you always copy on returning anyway.  Just make sure it’s move-friendly and optimization-friendly for other types such as large strings)

---

## bug

`std::begin` and `end` should be unqualified using the two-step.

```
using std::begin;
auto it1 = begin (container);
```

so that it picks up ADL for the container and handles built-in types (primitive array) too.

---

Suggest you offer *range* forms of your algorithms as well (or instead of) two-parameter versions.  E.g.

```
mconcat<std::plus>(str_vec.begin(), str_vec.end())
```

becomes simply

```
mconcat<std::plus>(str_vec)
```

(That also means you can use the range-for in the implementation)

```
for (auto item : inputrange)
    out = monoid<T, BinaryOp<T>>::mappend(out,item);
```

---

```
static std::string mempty(){return std::string{};}
```

note that now you can write:

```
static std::string mempty(){return {};}
```

and the type of thing you are constructing in the `return` statement is automatically taken from the return type of the function.

Comment: So users, probably me, will only supply a `UnitFor_v` specialization for their types and operations?

Comment: Does `unit` even have to be template parameter? And note, that `BinaryOp` already contains `T` inside (its kind is not `*→*`, it is a concrete application of binary operation constructor to monoid's value type), so `UnitFor_v` can be an unary template.

Comment: @bipll yes, there are examples with different monoids made using the same binary operation.  `std::plus<>` is itself generic and does not specify what type it is working on; you can apply it to `double` or `int` or (in one of his examples) to `string`.  Agree you could write that as `std::plus<double>` and not need T separately.

Answer (score 3):

@JDługosz has written a great answer, I just want to add that floating point multiplication is not associative. So the instance of Monoid for double is incorrect.

Proof:

```
int main()
{
    static_assert(
        (31415926535897.9323 *  299792458) * 14142135.6237 !=
         31415926535897.9323 * (299792458  * 14142135.6237)
    );
}
```

---

I [asked about this](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/8dn8vq/product_double_is_an_incorrect_monoid/) on the [/r/Haskell](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell) subreddit, and opinions there seem to be that while Monoid for double is maybe mathematically incorrect it's still useful and reasonable to have.